# $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$?!

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, profinite-groups

On this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer, we find the equation
$$\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$$
which says that the profinite completion of the integers equals the product over the various primes of the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Now, I just started reading up on this stuff, but this strikes me as a very strange thing. I would expect to have $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \subseteq \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$, but not equality. Why am I confused? Well, the definition 
$$\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \lim_\leftarrow \mathbb{Z} /{n\mathbb{Z}}$$
makes me want to think of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ as a sort of overgroup of all the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, a sort of largest group of formal integers which still manage to have well-defined remainders modulo every integer $n$.

On the other hand, each $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ and so, from the equation at the top, we have a copy of $\prod_p \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. This seems strange. Given a list of integers $x = (x_p)  \in \prod_p \mathbb{Z}$, how do I go about extracting the remainders of $x$ modulo various integers?

To ask a more concrete question, consider the element $x = (x_p)  \in \prod_p \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ with $x_2 = m \in \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $x_3 = n \in \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $x_p =0$ for $p \neq 2,3$. What is the remainder of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$? Presumably something constructible in terms of $m$ and $n$?

Comment: It reminds me of adeles and ideles studied in André Weil's "Number theory"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remainder of your $x$ in the last paragraph modulo $6$ is the unique
residue modulo $6$ solving $x\equiv m\pmod 2$ and $x\equiv n\pmod 3$.

In general let $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$. Then the remainder
of $x=(x_p)$ modulo $n$ is the simultaneous solution of $x\equiv x_{p_j}\pmod{p_j^{k_j}}$ for $j=1,\ldots,r$ (by the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: That's amazing! I don't know that I really appreciated the power of the Chinese remainder theorem before I saw its role here. For instance, the  CRT guarantees we can find a sequence of integers $x_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with the property that $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n}$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod{p^n}$ for the first $n$ odd primes $p$. Thus, in the limit, we get a profinite integer $x = \lim x_n \in \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ with the property that (1) $x \mapsto 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and (2) $x \mapsto 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for each odd prime $p$. By (1) $x$ seems "even", but by (2) $x$ seems to be "odd".

Comment: Depending on the point of view you are approaching from, it actually can seem very surprising that there is the freedom to achieve any set of remainders whatsoever, when you look modulo a very large but finite set of distinct prime powers. I feel quite impressed by this.